# I am getting two different output when using the same lubridate functions and I am not sure why

Tags: r, date, lubridate

I am new to R, and just started to use to the `library(lubridate)` package. I wanted to convert the dataframe formats, `sleep` and `intensity` to the same format and convert them from char to Date format.

The original dataframes,

`> head(sleep):`

```
          Id              SleepDay TotalSleepRecords TotalMinutesAsleep TotalTimeInBed
1 1503960366 4/12/2016 12:00:00 AM                 1                327            346
2 1503960366 4/13/2016 12:00:00 AM                 2                384            407
3 1503960366 4/15/2016 12:00:00 AM                 1                412            442
4 1503960366 4/16/2016 12:00:00 AM                 2                340            367
5 1503960366 4/17/2016 12:00:00 AM                 1                700            712
6 1503960366 4/19/2016 12:00:00 AM                 1                304            320
```

`> head(intensity)`:

```
          Id          ActivityHour TotalIntensity AverageIntensity
1 1503960366 4/12/2016 12:00:00 AM             20         0.333333
2 1503960366  4/12/2016 1:00:00 AM              8         0.133333
3 1503960366  4/12/2016 2:00:00 AM              7         0.116667
4 1503960366  4/12/2016 3:00:00 AM              0         0.000000
5 1503960366  4/12/2016 4:00:00 AM              0         0.000000
6 1503960366  4/12/2016 5:00:00 AM              0         0.000000
```

I ran the lubridate functions:

```
sleep$SleepDay=as.POSIXct(sleep$SleepDay, format="%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p", tz=Sys.timezone())
intensity$ActivityHour=as.POSIXct(intensity$ActivityHour, format="%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p", tz=Sys.timezone())
```

The output:

```
> head(sleep)
          Id   SleepDay TotalSleepRecords TotalMinutesAsleep TotalTimeInBed     date
1 1503960366 2016-04-12                 1                327            346 04/12/16
2 1503960366 2016-04-13                 2                384            407 04/13/16
3 1503960366 2016-04-15                 1                412            442 04/15/16
4 1503960366 2016-04-16                 2                340            367 04/16/16
5 1503960366 2016-04-17                 1                700            712 04/17/16
6 1503960366 2016-04-19                 1                304            320 04/19/16

> head(intensity)
          Id        ActivityHour TotalIntensity AverageIntensity
1 1503960366 2016-04-12 00:00:00             20         0.333333
2 1503960366 2016-04-12 01:00:00              8         0.133333
3 1503960366 2016-04-12 02:00:00              7         0.116667
4 1503960366 2016-04-12 03:00:00              0         0.000000
5 1503960366 2016-04-12 04:00:00              0         0.000000
6 1503960366 2016-04-12 05:00:00              0         0.000000
```

Why is it that the time is specified for the intensity dataframe but not for SleepDay? Did it remove it? The code seems identical...

Moreover, in the code it is the format is specified as `"%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p"` but the dataframe shows it as inverted `%Y/%m/%d`, why?. I know these questions may seem amaturish, but I want to understand the code in detail.

Thank you.

I tried to convery the date format, it worked but I want to understand the process.

Comment: (1) It looks like you're using `base::as.POSIXct`, not `lubridate`, though that doesn't change anything. (2) R is "slick" (I don't agree) in that when a time is perfectly midnight (for all in that column), it shows the date component only. But that's just how it is rendered to the screen, the underlying object is still a "midnight" timestamp as one would hope. If you do `sleep$SleepDay + 1`, you should see the time break out again.

Comment: Okay thank you! 

Do you know the answer to my second question, why the date switches?

Comment: R always always always shows `POSIXt`-class objects as `%Y-%m-%d`. Always. If you want it to be "time/number"-like, then it must be that way. When you render a report, table, or plot where you want it to be in a custom order, then you can use `format(Sys.time(), format="%d %b %Y %I:%M %P")` or however you prefer ... though after that point it is a _string_ and retains none of its number-like qualities (like the ability to add/subtract time from it, change time zones, etc).

Comment: Many people share frustration/confusion about this, many want to tell R to show it differently. There are some ways to get it to work some of the time, but nothing is pervasive enough to be an acceptable general solution. Sorry to say, but ... for now, I think just "accept" that it is in `%Y-%m-%d` format while working on a number-like time.

Answer (score 1):

R is just being slick: if all timestamps in a vector/column are effectively "midnight", then R hides the time component from what is *rendered to the screen*. The underlying object is still perfectly the same, it's a full timestamp.

Demonstration:

```r
tm <- as.POSIXct("4/12/2016 12:00:00 AM", format="%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")
tm + rep(0, 4)
# [1] "2016-04-12 EDT" "2016-04-12 EDT" "2016-04-12 EDT" "2016-04-12 EDT"
tm + 0:3
# [1] "2016-04-12 00:00:00 EDT" "2016-04-12 00:00:01 EDT" "2016-04-12 00:00:02 EDT" "2016-04-12 00:00:03 EDT"
```

Underneath, they're all just numbers with attributes:

```r
dput(tm + 0:4)
# structure(c(1460433600, 1460433601, 1460433602, 1460433603, 1460433604
# ), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"))
```

Answer (score 0):

A `tibble::tibble` will help you with this visualisation:

```
# tidyverse
tm <- as.POSIXct("4/12/2016 12:00:00 AM", format="%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")
tm <- tm + lubridate::days(1:4)

# Vector
> tm
[1] "2016-04-13 -03" "2016-04-14 -03" "2016-04-15 -03" "2016-04-16 -03"

# Matrix
> matrix(data = tm, ncol = 1)
           [,1]
[1,] 1460516400
[2,] 1460602800
[3,] 1460689200
[4,] 1460775600

# List
> list(tm)
[[1]]
[1] "2016-04-13 -03" "2016-04-14 -03" "2016-04-15 -03" "2016-04-16 -03"

# Data frame
> data.frame(date_time = tm)
   date_time
1 2016-04-13
2 2016-04-14
3 2016-04-15
4 2016-04-16

# Tibble
> tibble(date_time = tm)
# A tibble: 4 × 1
  date_time          
  <dttm>             
1 2016-04-13 00:00:00
2 2016-04-14 00:00:00
3 2016-04-15 00:00:00
4 2016-04-16 00:00:00
```